# DefaultDataPath is empty in VS2010 SQL2008 database deployment script

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, database-project

I have a VS2010 database project pointing to a SQL2005 database. When I deploy it, it correct picks up the DefaultDataPath from the SQL instance and everything works.

Today, I changed the project type from SQL205 to SQL2008 and changed the deploy properties to point to my SQL2008 server. However, now when I try to deploy, I get this error:

```
Error SQL01268: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 5105, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 A file activation error occurred. The physical file name '\AutoDeployedTRS.mdf' may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation.

Error SQL01268: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 1802, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

An error occurred while the batch was being executed.
```

The reason for this error is that the SQL script created by VS contain these three lines:

```
:setvar DatabaseName "AutoDeployedTRS"
:setvar DefaultDataPath "\"
:setvar DefaultLogPath "\"
```

If I check the SQL Instance properties (through the UI or by reading the registry), they are set correctly so it seems like VS2010 can't pick them up for some reason.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try to go to location Schema Objects\Database level objects\Storage\Files.
There can be found two files:
Open file [your_database_name].sql and make parameter 
    `FILENAME = '$(DefaultDataPath)$(DatabaseName).mdf'`.
Then open file [your_database_name]_log.sql and make parameter 
    `FILENAME = '$(DefaultDataPath)$(DatabaseName)_log.ldf'`.

After that try to deploy your project. This parameters now are defined during deployment according to current target database path. Hope it will help you.

Comment: This DB project doesn't have a Database Level Objects folder for some reason. It under Schema Objects, it has functions, security, stored procedures, tables and views.

Comment: This is grand and all, but this isn't an acceptable solution for database projects that get sync'd from a schema comparison on a regular basis.